# CodeIgniter-Access from model to controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following code in Model:

```
<?php
class Route_Model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getRoute($date = array())
    {
        try {
            $data = array(
                'route' => array(
                    'id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'budapest-athens',
                    'price' => 150,
                    'id' => 2,
                    'name' => 'rome-madrid',
                    'pret' => 250,
                    'id' => 3,
                    'name' => 'belgrade-bucharest',
                    'price' => 180,
                    'id' => 4
                )
            );
            return $data;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}?>
```

And I want to access array elements in my controller.

How can I access each field separately?

Something like `$price = $this->data['price']`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an array with two levels, if you want to get the `price` from the array `$data`, simply do this in your controller:

```
$data = $this->route_model->getRoute($date);
$price = $data['route']['price'];
```

Please, note that your array is not well formed because you have repeated keys and this may cause problems

Comment: Undefined variable 'date'... :/

Comment: `$date` is the variable you define on your `route_model` ... only you know what it should contain

Comment: Glad that helped! approve the answer if it worked ;)

Answer (score 2):

This array will never work since you're overwriting keys, I think you would want the following array:

```
$data = [
        'route' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'budapest-athens',
                'price' => 150
            ], [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'rome-madrid',
                'price' => 250
            ], [
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'belgrade-bucharest',
                'price' => 180
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Next to that, your try / catch seems unnecessary here, there is no real try. It's a hard-coded array, so unless this will actually do some interactions there is no need for the try / catch.

Anyway, to receive this data in your controller you should do:

```
$this->load->model('Route_model');
$route = $this->Route_model->getRoute();

var_dump($route);
exit;
```

Now you will have this array. Another wonder, are you actually trying to grab all the routes in this array, or is there something you want to do with the `$date` parameter? Since right now it doesn't looks like it's used unless you stripped some code away.